# What is the 'correct way' (from the compiler's point of view) for starting a line with a \ref{}?

Tags: warnings, ref

I write tex in vim and have an automatic linter. I write sentences in the same paragraph on separate lines (for clarity and version control) and I often want to use a `\ref{}` like a name to begin a line. Like this:

```
\ref{Q5*} shows that the two problems (or two instances of the same problem) can come apart.
If the two problems are distinct, then~\ref{Q5} has at least one problem which most questions do not.
Even if the problem of self-answering is a special case of the problem of pedantry (which I do not think it is) this at least shows that~\ref{Q5} has two different instances of the problem.
```

My linter gives me a warning message if I use a `\ref{}` in the middle of a line without a non-breaking space, so I use non-breaking spaces (second line of the block). But it gives me the same warning if I use `\ref{}` at the beginning of a line.

What should I be using to begin lines with `\ref{}` properly? (and why does the compiler throw warnings like this to begin with?) It seems odd to put a non-breaking space at the beginning of a line!

Thanks!

Comment: that is not a latex question but a problem of your editor/syntax checker.

Comment: Ah, at first I thought you wanted to capitalize the first letter of the \ref text (which would have been a more interesting question).

Comment: Which linter do you use?